# Drupal 7 context module fails to load on front page

Tags: 7

I have the context module installed on Drupal 7. It worked perfectly fine for a long time. But, recently when I try to add or remove a reaction(block) for a context the related page fails to load. I get an error: "The website encountered an unexpected error".

Has anyone had a problem like this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had another reaction added that was causing the issue. I removed the reaction and it seems to work now.